# Erro ao chamar Stored Procedure ORACLE pelo PHP passando data como parâmetro

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures

Tenho a seguinte Stored Procedure no Oracle:

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_RELATORIO(
    P_ID_SITUACAO  IN TB_PROSPECT.ID_SITUACAO%TYPE,
    P_ID_GRUPO IN TB_GRUPO.ID_GRUPO%TYPE,
    P_DT_INICIAL   IN TB_PROSPECT.DT_USUINC%TYPE --DATA DO ORACLE,,
    P_DT_FINAL     IN TB_PROSPECT.DT_USUINC%TYPE --DATA DO ORACLE,,
    P_CURSOR_DADOS OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS

  BEGIN
    --CORPO DA PROCEDURE
  END;
  
END SP_RELATORIO;
```

O código do PHP **(datas => 01-01-2020 00:00:00)**:

```html
$oracle_bd = $MYTNS;

$conn = OCILogon($oracle_usuario, $oracle_senha, $oracle_bd);

$sql = 'BEGIN SP_RELATORIO(:P_ID_SITUACAO, :P_ID_GRUPO, :P_DT_INICIAL, :P_DT_FINAL, :P_CURSOR_DADOS); END;';

$idSituacao = 'PAD';
$idGrupo = '2';
$dtaInicial = '01-01-2020 00:00:00';
$dtaTermino = '31-12-2020 00:00:00';

$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':P_ID_SITUACAO', $idSituacao);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':P_ID_GRUPO', $idGrupo);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':P_DT_INICIAL', $dtaInicial);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':P_DT_FINAL', $dtaTermino);

//But BEFORE statement, Create your cursor
$cursor = oci_new_cursor($conn);

// On your code add the latest parameter to bind the cursor resource to the Oracle argument
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":P_CURSOR_DADOS", $cursor, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);

// Execute the statement as in your first try
oci_execute($stmt); 

// and now, execute the cursor
oci_execute($cursor);

// Use OCIFetchinto in the same way as you would with SELECT
while ($data = oci_fetch_assoc($cursor, OCI_RETURN_LOBS)) {
    print_r($data);
}
```

O código acima com os respectivos formatos de datas retorna esse erro na linha 1 do Oracle:

***Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01843: not a valid month ORA-06512: at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste_relatorio_portabilidade\conn_oracle.php on line 47***

---

O código do PHP **(datas => 2020-01-01 00:00:00)**:

```html
$oracle_bd = $MYTNS;

$conn = OCILogon($oracle_usuario, $oracle_senha, $oracle_bd);

$sql = 'BEGIN SP_RELATORIO(:P_ID_SITUACAO, :P_ID_GRUPO, :P_DT_INICIAL, :P_DT_FINAL, :P_CURSOR_DADOS); END;';

$idSituacao = 'PAD';
$idGrupo = '2';
$dtaInicial = '2020-01-01 00:00:00';
$dtaTermino = '2020-12-31 00:00:00';

$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':P_ID_SITUACAO', $idSituacao);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':P_ID_GRUPO', $idGrupo);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':P_DT_INICIAL', $dtaInicial);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':P_DT_FINAL', $dtaTermino);

//But BEFORE statement, Create your cursor
$cursor = oci_new_cursor($conn);

// On your code add the latest parameter to bind the cursor resource to the Oracle argument
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":P_CURSOR_DADOS", $cursor, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);

// Execute the statement as in your first try
oci_execute($stmt); 

// and now, execute the cursor
oci_execute($cursor);

// Use OCIFetchinto in the same way as you would with SELECT
while ($data = oci_fetch_assoc($cursor, OCI_RETURN_LOBS)) {
    print_r($data);
}
```

O código acima com os respectivos formatos de datas retorna esse erro:

***Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01861: literal does not match format string ORA-06512: at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste_relatorio_portabilidade\conn_oracle.php on line 47***

---

O código do PHP **(datas => 01/01/2020 00:00:00)**:

```html
$oracle_bd = $MYTNS;

$conn = OCILogon($oracle_usuario, $oracle_senha, $oracle_bd);

$sql = 'BEGIN SP_RELATORIO(:P_ID_SITUACAO, :P_ID_GRUPO, :P_DT_INICIAL, :P_DT_FINAL, :P_CURSOR_DADOS); END;';

$idSituacao = 'PAD';
$idGrupo = '2';
$dtaInicial = '01/01/2020 00:00:00';
$dtaTermino = '31/12/2020 00:00:00';

$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':P_ID_SITUACAO', $idSituacao);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':P_ID_GRUPO', $idGrupo);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':P_DT_INICIAL', $dtaInicial);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':P_DT_FINAL', $dtaTermino);

//But BEFORE statement, Create your cursor
$cursor = oci_new_cursor($conn);

// On your code add the latest parameter to bind the cursor resource to the Oracle argument
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":P_CURSOR_DADOS", $cursor, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);

// Execute the statement as in your first try
oci_execute($stmt); 

// and now, execute the cursor
oci_execute($cursor);

// Use OCIFetchinto in the same way as you would with SELECT
while ($data = oci_fetch_assoc($cursor, OCI_RETURN_LOBS)) {
    print_r($data);
}
```

O código acima com os respectivos formatos de datas retorna esse erro na linha 1 do Oracle:

***Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01843: not a valid month ORA-06512: at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste_relatorio_portabilidade\conn_oracle.php on line 47***

Acredito que seja problema no formato de datas, mas já tentei várias conversões de formatos e não consegui. Se alguém puder me dar um help, agradeço muito!?

Comment: Já tentou `01-JAN-2020 00:00:00`? Referência: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01843.php

Comment: Augusto, nesse formato, retornou o seguinte erro: Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string ORA-06512: at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste_relatorio_portabilidade\conn_oracle.php on line 47

Comment: `$sql = 'BEGIN SP_RELATORIO(:P_ID_SITUACAO, :P_ID_GRUPO, to_date(:P_DT_INICIAL , 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24-MI-SS' ), to_date(:P_DT_FINAL, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24-MI-SS' ), :P_CURSOR_DADOS); END;';` e `$dtaInicial = '01-01-2020 00:00:00';
$dtaTermino = '31-12-2020 00:00:00';`

Comment: Augusto, retirei o horário da string e funcionou com o seguinte formato: $dtaInicial = '01-JAN-2015';
$dtaTermino = '30-DEC-2020';